# Почему скрипт сортировки по ширине и высоте «пропускает» некоторые изображения?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Есть php скрипт , который ресайзит изображения (ресайзит в зависимости от того что больше высота или ширина) , также нужно чтоб этот скрипт в зависимости от того что больше высота или ширина сохранял картинки в нужные папки.

С первым пунктом все нормально когда выполняется условие скрипт увеличивает высоту или ширину. А вот когда нужно сохранить в разные папки проблема. Например нужно когда высота больше сохранить в папку "height" или когда ширина больше то нужно сохранить в папку width.

А сейчас работает так, что 80 % процентов фотографий сохраняються правильно а остальные 20 попадают не в свою категорию: например если ширина больше то попадают в папку width. тоже самое и для высоты...

Вот часть кода отвечающая за условие:

```
 if($iWidth < $iHeight ){;resizeImage($imagePath,$destPath  =  $DestImagesDirectory_2.$file, $NewImageWidth, $NewImageHeight = 500,$Quality = 90); ;} 
 if($iWidth > $iHeight ){;resizeImage($imagePath,$destPath  =  $DestImagesDirectory.$file, $NewImageWidth = 500,$NewImageHeight,$Quality    = 90); ;}
```

Вот ниже весь код :

```js
<? php
//Maximize script execution time
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

//Initial settings, Just specify Source and Destination Image folder.
$ImagesDirectory = 'C:\Users\Sun\Desktop\origin-picture-logo/'; //Source Image Directory End with Slash
$DestImagesDirectory = 'D:\width/'; //Destination Image Directory End with Slash
$DestImagesDirectory_2 = 'D:\height/';
$NewImageWidth; //New Width of Image
$NewImageHeight; // New Height of Image
$Quality; //Image Quality



//Function that resizes image.
function resizeImage($SrcImage, $DestImage, $MaxWidth = 20, $MaxHeight = 29, $Quality = 90) {

  global $iWidth;
  global $iHeight;
  global $img;


  list($iWidth, $iHeight, $type) = getimagesize($SrcImage);
  $ImageScale = min($MaxWidth / $iWidth, $MaxHeight / $iHeight);
  $NewWidth = ceil($ImageScale * $iWidth);
  $NewHeight = ceil($ImageScale * $iHeight);
  $NewCanves = imagecreatetruecolor($NewWidth, $NewHeight);



  switch (strtolower(image_type_to_mime_type($type))) {

    case 'image/jpeg':
      $NewImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($SrcImage);
      break;
    case 'image/png':
      $NewImage = imagecreatefrompng($SrcImage);

      break;
    case 'image/gif':
      $NewImage = imagecreatefromgif($SrcImage);
      break;
    default:
      return false;
  }




  // Resize Image
  if (imagecopyresampled($NewCanves, $NewImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $NewWidth, $NewHeight, $iWidth, $iHeight)) {
    // echo $iWidth;
    $stndartwidth = $iWidth;
    // copy file
    if (imagejpeg($NewCanves, $DestImage, $Quality)) {
      imagedestroy($NewCanves);
      return true;
    }
  }
}


//Open Source Image directory, loop through each Image and resize it.

if ($dir = opendir($ImagesDirectory)) {
  while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {

    $imagePath = $ImagesDirectory.$file;
    global $destPath;
    $checkValidImage = @getimagesize($imagePath);

    if (file_exists($imagePath) && $checkValidImage) //Continue only if 2 given parameters are true
    {
      //Image looks valid, resize.

      if ($iWidth < $iHeight) {;
        resizeImage($imagePath, $destPath = $DestImagesDirectory_2.$file, $NewImageWidth, $NewImageHeight = 500, $Quality = 90);;
      } //
      if ($iWidth > $iHeight) {;
        resizeImage($imagePath, $destPath = $DestImagesDirectory.$file, $NewImageWidth = 500, $NewImageHeight, $Quality = 90);;
      } //


      if (resizeImage($imagePath, $destPath, $NewImageWidth, $NewImageHeight, $Quality)) {

        echo $file.
        ' resize Success!<br />';
        /*
        Now Image is resized, may be save information in database?
        */

      } else {

        echo $file.
        ' resize Failed!<br />';

      }
    }
  }
  // echo  $imagePath;
  closedir($dir);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, вы сравниваете не те параметры. Переменные `$iWidth` и `$iHeight` инициализируются только при вызове функции `resizeImage`. Во-вторых, у вас не обрабатывается ситуация, когда ширина и высота изображения равны. В-третьих, у вас зачем-то два раза подряд вызывается функция `resizeImage`.

Вот исправленный код:

```
<? php
//Maximize script execution time
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

//Initial settings, Just specify Source and Destination Image folder.
$ImagesDirectory = 'C:\Users\Sun\Desktop\origin-picture-logo/'; //Source Image Directory End with Slash
$DestImagesDirectory = 'D:\width/'; //Destination Image Directory End with Slash
$DestImagesDirectory_2 = 'D:\height/';
$NewImageWidth; //New Width of Image
$NewImageHeight; // New Height of Image
$Quality; //Image Quality



//Function that resizes image.
function resizeImage($SrcImage, $DestImage, $MaxWidth = 20, $MaxHeight = 29, $Quality = 90) {

  global $iWidth;
  global $iHeight;
  global $img;


  list($iWidth, $iHeight, $type) = getimagesize($SrcImage);
  $ImageScale = min($MaxWidth / $iWidth, $MaxHeight / $iHeight);
  $NewWidth = ceil($ImageScale * $iWidth);
  $NewHeight = ceil($ImageScale * $iHeight);
  $NewCanves = imagecreatetruecolor($NewWidth, $NewHeight);



  switch (strtolower(image_type_to_mime_type($type))) {

    case 'image/jpeg':
      $NewImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($SrcImage);
      break;
    case 'image/png':
      $NewImage = imagecreatefrompng($SrcImage);

      break;
    case 'image/gif':
      $NewImage = imagecreatefromgif($SrcImage);
      break;
    default:
      return false;
  }


  // Resize Image
  if (imagecopyresampled($NewCanves, $NewImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $NewWidth, $NewHeight, $iWidth, $iHeight)) {
    //  echo    $iWidth;
    $stndartwidth = $iWidth;
    // copy file
    if (imagejpeg($NewCanves, $DestImage, $Quality)) {
      imagedestroy($NewCanves);
      return true;
    }
  }
}


//Open Source Image directory, loop through each Image and resize it.

if ($dir = opendir($ImagesDirectory)) {
  while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {

    $imagePath = $ImagesDirectory.$file;
    global $destPath;
    $checkValidImage = @getimagesize($imagePath);

    if (file_exists($imagePath) && $checkValidImage) //Continue only if 2 given parameters are true
    {
      //Image looks valid, resize.

      if ($checkValidImage[0] < $checkValidImage[1]) {
        $destPath = $DestImagesDirectory_2.$file;
        $NewImageWidth = $checkValidImage[0];
        $NewImageHeight = 500;
        $Quality = 90;
      } else {
        $destPath = $DestImagesDirectory.$file;
        $NewImageWidth = 500;
        $NewImageHeight = $checkValidImage[1];
        $Quality = 90;
      }

      if (resizeImage($imagePath, $destPath, $NewImageWidth, $NewImageHeight, $Quality)) {
        echo $file.
        ' resize Success!<br />';
        /*
        Now Image is resized, may be save information in database?
        */

      } else {

        echo $file.
        ' resize Failed!<br />';

      }
    }
  }
  //    echo  $imagePath;
  closedir($dir);
}

?>
```